# print sum if all inputs are valid otherwise print "Invalid" in c++

Tags: c++, g++, stringstream

The problem is to print sum of all integers in one input line.If any of the input is not valid print "Invalid".
This is the code --> [C++ Code Link](http://pastebin.com/AQFUzLGQ)

The problem with the code is that it doesn't produces output if **input > 9**

.How should I approach here?

```
input : 1 2 3 14
output : 11 //which is wrong
input : 1 a 2 b
output : Invalid
```

Comment: Please avoid posting link to external sites. Edit your question and paste the code in your question.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Telling people to paste the code here usually yields still OT code dumps. Better tell them to post a [mcve] instead.

Comment: What do you mean the 'above' input gives you a compilation error? What's the input you're talking about? How do you define valid? The input you posted compiles fine.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 16 of your code:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i)
```

You compare `i`, which is a signed integer, to `v.size()`, which is of the unsigned type `size_t`. Replace `int` by `size_t`:

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i)
```

Comment: Ahh yes! Thank you very much.But the problem with the code is that it produces output only if input is a single digit.What if input is > 9 ?

Comment: @krishnakeshav If you have another question, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop use `unsigned` instead of `int` and it will solve the problem.
You are comparing `i` with is signed int with an `unsigned v.size()`.

Comment: This also works.However, I would prefer using 'size_t'.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store `14` in a `char` which will not work! Everything will be fine with single digit numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) because they are seen as a single character, but `14` contains two characters, so firstly `1` will be added in the vector, then `4`. So, the answer 11 is correct because 1+2+3+1+4=11! You can either use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/289372/3185860 or the `strtok` alternative to divide the input string and get the numbers (in this case, the `' '` will be your delimiter character) or parse the input in another way to store the numbers in an `int` variable.

Edit: I see you still can't understand what you have to do. It took 2 minutes to modify the response from the link I commented below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321175/3185860 ) to solve your problem... Next time, please spend more time trying to solve it yourself.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t ReadNumbers( const string & s, vector <int> & v ) {
    istringstream is( s );
    int n;

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) if(isalpha(s[i]) && s[i]!=' ') return 0;

    while( is >> n ) {
        v.push_back( n );
    }

    return v.size();
}

int main() {
    int sum=0;
    string s;
    vector <int> v;
    getline( cin, s );
    ReadNumbers( s, v );
    if(v.size()==0){ cout<<"Invalid\n"; return 0;}
    else{
        for ( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
            sum = sum + v[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<sum<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show me example code?

Comment: Look at the link i posted in the answer. You will have to store the whole input in a string (not in a vector of characters), then do what the link says, but instead of '-', you will have '   ' and when you find a number, convert it to an int and add it to the sum.

Comment: This answer does what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1321175/3185860

Comment: Tried link given by you.It stops accepting input if it is not valid.But how am I suppose to check for end of line or if input is invalid?

Comment: @krishnakeshav look at the edited answer. Next time, try to think more. This is not a place to solve homeworks.

Comment: Also, a thank you is more than welcome.