# Add integers to array using cin simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

Hellow guys i want to add nine integers to array at once time without pressing enter key in run time. please guys tell me how to add nine integers to array simultaneously in C++.
 Thanks!

Comment: `std::cin` a `std::string` instead and parse it with some rule for deleminators.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321154/3754223

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String containing several numbers into integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321137/convert-string-containing-several-numbers-into-integers)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process each integer value right after its input in console is complete (e.g. in that a blank indicates that the next integer value shall begin), you are in a bad position.

The reason is that terminal input (beyond of what your C++ program can influence) often is buffered, and even `cin` might not receive any character until `Enter` or `EOF` is pressed in the terminal.

There may exist workarounds like `conio.h` or `ncurses`, but the are not standard and probably not worth the effort in your situation unless you really need to implement integer scanning for a production environment tightly connected to console input.

Try it out and compare input taken directly from console to input from a stream that is already "filled" with enough input:

```
int main() {

    stringstream ss("12 34 56 78 90 10 11 12 13");
    //istream &in = ss;   // would output each integer immediately.

    istream &in = cin;  // will probably wait for enter before processing begins.

    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if (! (in >> value))
            break;
        cout << value << "; ";
    }   
}
```